# Does the ordering of calls to sequential() and parallel() matter when processing a Java 8 stream pipeline?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

Does the placement of calls to `sequential()` and `parallel()` change how a Java 8 stream's pipeline is executed?

For example, suppose I have this code:

```
new ArrayList().stream().parallel().filter(...).count();
```

In this example, it's pretty clear that `filter()` will run in parallel. However, what if I have this code:

```
new ArrayList().stream().filter(...).parallel().count();
```

Does `filter()` still run in parallel or does it run sequentially? The reason it's not clear is because intermediate operations like `filter()` are lazy, i.e., they won't run until a terminal operation is invoked like `count()`. As such, by the time `count()` is invoked, we have a parallel stream pipeline but is `filter()` performed sequentially because it came *before* the call to `parallel()`?

Comment: Based on the javadoc and the source code, I'm inclined to say they're the same.

Comment: @shmosel To which JavaDoc are referring? I wasn't able to find any documentation on this sort of thing. Also, keep in mind that even though the Java implementation may do one thing, third-party streams (i.e., those also implementing the Java 8 Stream API) may do something different, so I would be more interested in the documentation/specification of how this is *supposed* to work.

Comment: The Javadoc to [`parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) seems to imply that it is (or may be?) applied to the entire pipeline. I'm aware that it's a little vague, which is why this is just a comment. As a side note, a similar question can be asked about `unordered()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note the end of [the `Stream`’s class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Stream pipelines may execute either sequentially or in parallel. This execution mode is a property of the stream. Streams are created with an initial choice of sequential or parallel execution. (For example, Collection.stream() creates a sequential stream, and Collection.parallelStream() creates a parallel one.) This choice of execution mode may be modified by the BaseStream.sequential() or BaseStream.parallel() methods, and may be queried with the BaseStream.isParallel() method.

In other words, calling `sequential()` or `parallel()` only changes a property of the stream and its state at the point when the terminal operation is commenced determines the execution mode of the entire pipeline.

This might not be documented that clearly at all places, because, it wasn’t always so. In the early development there were prototypes having different mode for the stages. [This mail](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-March/001504.html) from March 2013 explains the change.

Comment: I wonder what happens when you set it *and then* un-set it. like `filter.parallel.map.sequantial`. I assume last one wins?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that at least in the standard Oracle Java 8 implementation, although the `parallel()` method is defined as an "intermediate operation", it is not exactly lazy. That is, it has an immediate effect, regardless of whether you have a terminal operation or not. Consider the following example:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        System.out.println(s.isParallel());
        Stream<Integer> s1 = s.parallel();
        System.out.println(s.isParallel());
        System.out.println(s == s1);
    }

}
```

The output on my machine is:

```
false
true
true
```

Which tells us that `parallel()` immediately changes the state of the underlying stream (and returns that stream).

However, the Javadoc is written in such a way that it *allows* this, but does not *require* this. Which means that other stream implementations are free to execute the operations before the `parallel()` operations in a different execution mode than those after it.

In short, it's not a behavior you can rely on, either way.

Comment: Whether the `parallel()` method returns a new instance is irrelevant. All intermediate operations are allowed to modify the `Stream` instance instead of returning a new one. But if they return a new instance, it’s forbidden to use tho old one afterwards, so the effect is the same. You always have only a single valid `Stream` instance encapsulating the entire pipeline state. And `parallel()` is as lazy as you can imagine, `.parallel().sequential()` has no effect at all.

Comment: @Holger, what do you mean by "It is forbidden to use the old one afterwards"? Where is that rule written? It is true that you can't consume from it once you have consumed from the derived stream, but that doesn't mean that you can't use that object behind the scenes.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Does your answer imply that a stream whose `isParallel()` method returns true will execute the *entire* pipeline in parallel?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I’m not talking about things behind the scenes. I’m talking about the fact that you always have only one valid front-end `Stream` instance, which reports to be either, parallel or sequential. There is no “`.parallelBeforeThatStage()`” method in the API. So whether `.parallel()` returns a new object or not, is irrelevant. There still could be hidden state in an object not reachable through the API. That’s not sufficient to assume the behavior.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian not if there are other stream implementations along the pipeline it which are not implemented in the same way.